# hibernate - definition of relationships - why?

Tags: sql, hibernate

What's the point or advantages of joining tables using hibernate, such as:

- `@OneToMany`
- `@ManyToOne`
- `@ManyToMany`
- `@JoinColumn`

if there are relationships defined on the database level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main advantages:

Being able to navigate between persistent objects:

```
order.getProduct().getSupplier().getCompany().getAddress().getStreet();
```

Being able to use joins in HQL (or Criteria) queries:

```
select address.street from Order order 
inner join order.product product
inner join product.supplier supplier
inner join supplier.company company
inner join company.address address
where order.id = :id
```

In fact, I would say associations is what makes an ORM an ORM. Without them you would only get basic objects, not linked to any other objects, and using JDBC would be enough.

Comment: Aha, it makes sense. I used to mapping database views and working with them, but it's too complicated if I'm thinking about it now. This sounds much better. Thank you

Comment: As I discovered, `select address.street from Order order where...` should be enough, if the relationships are mapped in entities. In fact, with joins it doesn't work (watch this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995993/hibernate-iterating-query) if you want :-)

Comment: It works perfectly with joins. You just have to understand what the query returns. If you select address.street selects only the streets, and returns a `List<String>`. I never use HQL without a select clause, because it makes it clear what is returned from the query.

Comment: That's how I understood it, but what if you want to select some columns from one table, some from other... is it possible? Do the joins have sense if it works without them?

Comment: Of course it is. Read the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select

Comment: I'd better get into it deeper. Anyway, thank you, you've show me the way and I find it very helpful and valuable!