# hibernate - iterating query

Tags: hibernate

I have two testing tables associated by foreign key

- table `School` (with fk on `student_id`)
- table `Students` (with pk on `id`)
- FK: `school.student_id -> students.id`

How can I get students name using this query?

```
Session session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
String query = "";
Query criteria;

query = "from School s " +
        "inner join s.student st " +
        "where s.student_id = st.id";
criteria = session.createQuery(query);
```

When I try to iterate data:

```
for(Iterator<?> iter = criteria.iterate(); iter.hasNext();)
{
  Object item = (Object)iter.next();
  System.out.println(((School) item).getStudent().getId());
}
```

it reports:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to table.School
```

but mapping is working, because when i've changed the last row to

`System.out.println(item.toString());`

I've got all the data but like that:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1d2300e
[Ljava.lang.Object;@51207c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2bd615
...
```

Comment: Please show which package does `Query criteria` uses?

Comment: What do you mean? This? import org.hibernate.Query;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HQL, whenever you join without an explicit select clause Hibernate returns all the joined entities.  Its not the most intuitive thing, buts it is legacy behavior at this point.

Secondly you are re-stating the join condition between school and student.  You already specified that in the mapping, so Hibernate knows that when you say "join s.student" in the query.  So the where clause is unnecessary here.

You data model seems a bit backwards I think from what most think of School/Student relationship.  Generally a school has multiple students (a student being a person in a particular relationship with the school).  But given the model as you describe...

You have not stated exactly what you want out of this query, but your original query is returning all students.  No idea why you even "drive" the query from the School object.

```
Session session = ...;
List<Student> results = (List<Students>) session.createQuery( "select s from Students s" ).list();
for ( Student student : results ) {
    // handle each student
}
```

If you want just the names of the students (which you sort-of/kind-of imply):

```
Session session = ...;
List<String> results = (List<String>) session.createQuery( "select s.name from Students s" ).list();
for ( String student : results ) {
    // handle each student name
}
```

Note that the select clause is really optional in my above queries because there is only one entity referenced in the from clause.  I prefer to always specify a select clause to be explicit.

Comment: Btw, it was a testing example, I did't thought much about school and students relationship. It was only for test, so ofcourse you're right, student have to point to the school where he's study :-)

Comment: No worries, I understand.  But over the years I've learned to look at the db mapping rather than rely on "usual conceptions" ;)  Just in future it usually makes getting an answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterator is of type Object. Try typing it with School.

```
for(Iterator<School> iter=criteria.iterate();iter.hasNext();){...}
```

Since that did not seem to work try the following.

```
String sql="...";
Query query=session.createQuery(sql);
List<School> schools=(List<School>)query.list();
    for(School school:schools)
        System.out.println(school.getStudent().getId());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried it. It doesn't work... same error message

Comment: Did you change the type of item to School as well?

Comment: Jj, I've tried all the combinations and It can be iterated only over the Object..

Comment: As a side note, have you considered using the EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory opposed to working with the session since these are part of JPA and not Hibernate Specific (not sure if this is an option)? This would allow you to write your code a little more cleanly as well. You could write something like em.createQuery(sql,School.class).getResultList();

Comment: Thank you, but it's completely the same. It works as Object type, not works as school type :(

Comment: I've tried print `item.getId()` from `school`, or `item.getStudent().getId` from `school.student` .. seems to be mapped fine, seems to be working, but only as an Object. I'm new in this kind of mapping, but I suppose, object School should be enough

Comment: Still get the exception, with or without toString()

Comment: Do you still have item typed as Object (as Object school) or is it typed as school (as School school)? Did you try running the second piece of code as it is, or did you modify parts of it? I only ask because that should work, I am confused why it doesnt.

Comment: School school. I have to go in several minutes, but I'll create complete question tomorow, with both entities, school and student, because as I said, I'm new in hibernate mappings. Maybe is the error somewhere else.. I suppose the tables and also the object are resolved from query, and when I iterating over these objects, it should work. But perhaps I forgot something..... anyway, thanks!

Comment: [Ljava.lang.Object; is the way Java represents an array of Object type.  You might also see [Lbyte; etc.  The problem is the use of the join and the lack of an explicit join clause as I explain in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm not awake yet...   I didnt look closely at the query. I just saw the typing issues and wanted to knock that out as a cause.

Comment: Steve is right. Problem was with the join in query. The simple "from Student s" covers it.. Anyway, thanks. Btw. the undeserved down vote is not from me..

Comment: I did the down vote.  Isnt that what down votes are for?  To mark an answer as incorrect?

Comment: I agree that is what they are for. I would have just deleted this answer if there weren't the other typing/casting issues in the question which I was addressing, along with the suggestion to look into switching to using the entity manager (JPA) vs Hibernates specific API.